# Delete row button in alv grid in sap

Tags: grid, toolbar, abap, alv

I am using function **"REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY"** in order to display a grid. My problem is that not all the buttons in ALV toolbar are displayed. For example, I can not see the **"delete row"** button.

This is my call:

```
  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'    
  EXPORTING
     IT_FIELDCAT   = fieldcatalog
  TABLES
      t_outtab     = lt_files_records_final    
  EXCEPTIONS
     PROGRAM_ERROR = 1
     OTHERS        = 2.
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

IF you need the full editor functionality (including cell editors), you will have to move away from the (obsolete and unsupported) function module to the class `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID`. See the documentation [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/df/ef7f380c2f2e3ce10000009b38f8cf/content.htm).

If you only need a delete button, it might be easier to add a custom button. Check the program `SALV_DEMO_TABLE_FUNCTIONS` for an example (and start using the ALV OM instead of the old function modules - much easier to code with).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to create a custom button.

Comment: The example uses a screen. I don't have to use a screen. I was told to use a report in order to display some records and according to user's selections. The user must also be able to delete these records, so I am trying to find a way to do this. Is this feasible without using a screen?

Comment: [Yes.](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp2004/helpdata/en/41/b22041d69ba52fe10000000a155106/content.htm)